# MacOS 10.14.6 Library not loaded: @rpath/libIrrXMLd.dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, assimp

When I ran a C++ application in XCode on MacOS 10.14 that uses OpenGL and Assimp, everything compiled, but I got this error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libIrrXMLd.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libassimpd.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

Searched on Google and seems like no one has had this problem before

Comment: Are you linking that library?  Does it show up in your application bundle?  (Apparently libassimpd needs it.)

Comment: I am not linking that library, I am only linking Assimp.